# Don't display template field of SPGridView in filtering!

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have a web part with SPGridView. I defined TemplateField for SPGridView.

```
 TemplateField tmp = new TemplateField();
 tmp.HeaderText = field.Title;
 tmp.ItemTemplate = new AddTemplateToGridView(ListItemType.Header, field.InternalName);
 grid.Columns.Add(tmp);
```

when load page, all data display , but when filter or sort a column , **don't display item in template field.**

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your code to add the column is not in a method that is called on post back.

I recommend reviewing the ASP.NET control lifecycle.